# SDL2 Loading font outside of the function raises error

Tags: c++, sdl, truetype

I have created a function that renders a text to the screen, I'm doing it using SDL2_ttf I am opening a font like this:

```
TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont("font.ttf",50);
```

Unfortunately I have got several functions that are rendering some text to the screen so I don't want to create local font variable in every single function that renders a text, so I realized that I can put:

```
TTF_Font *font = NULL;
```

to my class and then just assign a font to it in Constructor or any function which will load it (of course that function will be called before using the font).

So let's say we have a constructor:

```
Class::Class(){
font = TTF_OpenFont("font.ttf",50); //the font should be loaded now (declared in class)
}
```

I should be able to use it in every member function but it always raises a segmentation error, I basically cannot use a font without loading it and defining it inside a function that I'm using it, whats wrong? 
I can't help myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solved , i had to call ttf init in this class also because i was initing the ttf in baseclass but the constructor in this class was called before the init in base class was called (this secondary class is a member of baseclass)